# Remove tiktok video logo/watermark using laravel/ffmpeg?

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, video-watermarking

How I can remove tiktok video logo/watermark using FFmpeg? Like most sites are doing e.g https://ssstik.io/en

I tried to remove the logo using delogo filter https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg but it leaves a blur effect in the video while the above site logo removal is clean, with no blurry effect.

Sample code:

```
$video = FFMpeg::open('public/tiktok/video2.mp4');
$video->addFilter(function ($filters) use ($bottom_coordinates) {
        $filters->custom( 'delogo=x=10:y=10:w=150:h=77');
 })
 ->export()
 ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264)
 ->toDisk('public')
 ->save('7118695488282447131_delogo.mp4');
```

Any help?
Thanks in advance.